# ERROR : ‘fuse_operations_compat2’ has no non-static data member named ‘readdir’

Tags: c++, fuse

I am trying to build a simple filesystem using fuse 2.9.7 to store an avifile in it. But i am having trouble in finding the solution for these error.

```
‘fuse_operations_compat2’ has no non-static data member named ‘readdir’
```

I have this main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fuse.h>

#include "include/AVIContainer.h"
#include "include/Fuse.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  AVIContainer *avi = new AVIContainer(320, 240, 30, 90);
  avi->WriteToFile("test.avi");


struct fuse_operations oper = {
    .getattr    = getattr_callback,
    .readdir    = readdir_callback,
    .open       = open_callback,
    .read       = read_callback,
};

   return fuse_main(argc, argv , &oper);

}
```

and these are the header file(.cpp)

```
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 30

#include<fuse.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include "Fuse.h"


char filename[30] = "/avifile";
char filename2[30] = "avifile"; 


int getattr_callback(const char *path, struct stat *st)
{

      st->st_uid = getuid();
      st->st_gid = getgid();
      st->st_atime = time(NULL);
      st->st_mtime = time(NULL);

      if(strcmp(path, "/") == 0)
      {
          st->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;
          st->st_nlink = 2;
      }

      if(strcmp(path,filename) == 0)
      {  
          st->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0644;
          st->st_nlink = 1;
          st->st_size = datasize;
      }

      return 0;       
}


int readdir_callback(const char *path, void *buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{

       filler(buffer, ".", NULL, 0);
       filler(buffer, "..", NULL, 0);

       if(strcmp(path, "/") == 0)
       {
           filler(buffer, filename2, NULL, 0);           
       }

       return 0;
}

int read_callback(const char *path, char *buffer, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{

       unsigned int SizetoRead = size;

       if(  (offset + size) > datasize)
       {
            SizetoRead = datasize - offset;
       }

       memcpy(buffer, databuffer + offset, SizetoRead);      

       return SizetoRead;
}

int open_callback(const char *path, fuse_file_info *fi)
{        

    return 0;
}
```

and this is .h file

```
#ifndef FUSE
#define FUSE


#include <fuse.h>

uint8_t* get_data();

unsigned int get_size();

int getattr_callback(const char *path, struct stat *st);

int read_callback(const char *path, char *buffer, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi);

int readdir_callback(const char *path, void *buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi);

int open_callback(const char *path, fuse_file_info *fi);

#endif
```

I think the problem is with version of fuse , though not sure.
please help, thanks in advance

Edit:

Comment: Even in the fuse.h file of source code of fuse 2.9.7 , function readdir is defined , so it means it is not even version issue , but still it is giving error.  Please help

Comment: It might be caused due to the first #include <fuse.h> in main.cpp being before the #define FUSE_USE_VERSION 30. Try commenting it out.

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes that might be the reason , I have removed it and now few new errors have appeared with fuse ,. It says error :: missing initializer for fuse_operations_compat2::mkdir '

Comment: https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html,  the above was just an example , same error messages for all the function defined in the a above link , more example .error ::missing initializer for fuse_opertion_campat2::flush

Comment: Perhaps try not using a "designated initializer", struct s = { .a = x, .b = y }, but rather just every member func in a line: struct s; s.a = x; s.b = y; ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the high level fuse ops (vs the low level ones).
here is what you can do with it (fuse_compat.h)

```
struct fuse_operations_compat2 {
    int (*getattr)     (const char *, struct stat *);
    int (*readlink)    (const char *, char *, size_t);
    int (*getdir)      (const char *, fuse_dirh_t, fuse_dirfil_t_compat);
    int (*mknod)       (const char *, mode_t, dev_t);
    int (*mkdir)       (const char *, mode_t);
    int (*unlink)      (const char *);
    int (*rmdir)       (const char *);
    int (*symlink)     (const char *, const char *);
    int (*rename)      (const char *, const char *);
    int (*link)    (const char *, const char *);
    int (*chmod)       (const char *, mode_t);
    int (*chown)       (const char *, uid_t, gid_t);
    int (*truncate)    (const char *, off_t);
    int (*utime)       (const char *, struct utimbuf *);
    int (*open)    (const char *, int);
    int (*read)    (const char *, char *, size_t, off_t);
    int (*write)       (const char *, const char *, size_t, off_t);
    int (*statfs)      (const char *, struct statfs *);
    int (*flush)       (const char *);
    int (*release)     (const char *, int);
    int (*fsync)       (const char *, int);
    int (*setxattr)    (const char *, const char *, const char *, size_t, int);
    int (*getxattr)    (const char *, const char *, char *, size_t);
    int (*listxattr)   (const char *, char *, size_t);
    int (*removexattr) (const char *, const char *);
```

};

try having the version as 32

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.cpp`, the `fuse.h` Header is included before the version is set, so when your main file is compiled (where the readdir is supposed to be set), FUSE is loaded in compatibility mode. Removing the `#include<fuse.h>` from your main file should solve the problem as FUSE is then included via your header file, which sets the correct version.